# List of Ordered Json properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a class as shown below and I am using JSON.NET to serialize/deserialize

```
public class Car
{
  [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
  public int CarId {get; set;}
  [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
  public string CarName {get; set;}
  [JsonIgnore]
  public int CarMfgDate {get; set}
  [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
  public int CarCapacity {get; set;}
}
```

I need to get a list of all Json-visible properties in the same order as defined by the 'JsonProperty' attribute in the class above. So, I would want the list to be initialized as below for the 'Car' class.

```
List<string> columns = GetOrderedJSONProperties();

Console.WriteLine(columns.Count); //Prints "3"
Console.WriteLine(columns[0]); //Prints "CarName"
Console.WriteLine(columns[1]); //Prints "CarCapacity"
Console.WriteLine(columns[2]); //Prints "CarId"
```

Please help me write the GetOrderedJSONProperties() method. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linqs `OrderBy` function for that:

```
var columns = typeof(Car).GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>() == null)
    .OrderBy(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>()?.Order)
    .Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: This worked with a few changes. I have pasted the changed code below. 
`var columns = typeof(Car).GetProperties()
                            .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute), false) == null || p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute), false).Length == 0)
                            .OrderBy(p => ((JsonPropertyAttribute[])p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), false))[0].Order)
                            .Select(p => p.Name).ToList();` . Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I am accepting this answer with the above caveat.

Comment: @lefou the attribute getter with  types exist as an extension method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link @Nico!